# Forwarding traffic to custom key chain in iptables

Tags: linux, unix, iptables

I need help regarding iptables. I have the following iptables rules when i use the command iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)

target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)

target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain MYSSH (0 references)

target     prot opt source               destination
```

Now I want to add a rule to the `INPUT` chain of my filter table that will send all ssh traffic to the `MYSSH` chain. I have to make sure this new rule follows (not precedes) the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule, so it doesn't apply to existing connections!

I tried:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m MYSSH --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

but this is not working. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is kind of a question for Superuser, but okay. I have my admin hat on today. :P

The main thing is that you can use your chain as a target like `ACCEPT`, `REJECT` or `DROP`, so you want to pass it as `-j` option, i.e.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j MYSSH
```

would append a rule to pipe all TCP traffic to port 22 through the `MYSSH` chain to the `INPUT` chain.

The other question is where to insert this rule. Generally, when I do this kind of stuff manually (these days I usually use shorewall because its easier to maintain), I just work with `iptables -A` commands and run them in the right order. In your case, it looks as though you want to insert it as the second or third rule, before the catchall

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

rule (although that might have some additionall conditions that `iptables -L` will not show without `-v`; I can't know that). Then we're looking at

```
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 22 -j MYSSH
```

or

```
iptables -I INPUT 3 -p tcp --dport 22 -j MYSSH
```

depending on where you want it.

Note, by the way, that if this catch-all rule doesn't have additional conditions that I'm not seeing, the rule below it will never be reached.